# Java Multithreading Matrix Multiply

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my code for multiplying matricies in parallel:

```
public void multiplyParallel() {
    int numProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    int step = (int)MATRIX_SIZE/numProcessors;
    for (int i=0; i<numProcessors; i++)  {
        Runnable r = new MatrixMultiply(this.start, this.end);
        new Thread(r).start();
        this.start += step;
        this.end += step;
    }
    this.start = 0;
    this.end = 0;
}

@Override
public void run() { 
    for (int i=this.start; i<this.end; i++) 
        for (int j=this.start; j<this.end; j++)
            for (int k=this.start; k<this.end; k++)
                this.matrix3[i][j] = this.matrix1[i][k] * this.matrix2[k][j];
}
```

But when I run this code on a 1024x1024 matrix, it only runs for 2-3 ms, whereas a serial version runs for around 1 second. I should be expecting 1/(numProcessors) time for the parallel version at the best.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? The run() method is being called the same number of times as there are processors on my machine.

Comment: Are you comparing it to similarly blocked single processor code, with the same step size? There is a big gain in cache efficiency for working on smaller blocks.

Comment: Yes, I am comparing it to single-processor version (which has the same loop body as the run method here does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Yea.  You are not multiplying the matrices.  What you are actually doing is (in effect) slicing the matrices into submatrices, and then multiply the *subset* of those matrices that sit on the diagonal of the original matrix.

I suggest you compare the results of the two versions of the computation ... and draw your own conclusions from that.

---

Effective parallelization of matrix multiplication is not a simple issue.

Here are a couple of relevant links, albeit at a general level:

- http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~yelick/cs267-sp04/lectures/13/lect13-pmatmul-6x.pdf - starting at about slide 17.
- http://www.slideshare.net/pkpramit/matrix-multiplicationan-example-of-concurrent-programming
- [Parallel Matrix Multiplication in Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484204/parallel-matrix-multiplication-in-java-6) ... includes some Java code (YMMV).

Also note that according to Wikipedia, there are [more efficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) non-parallel algorithms than "naive" (`O(N^3)`) multiplication.

Comment: Not even that because OP is missing a sum.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even notice that. How would I make it so each thread only works on 1/(numProcessors) of the original matrix?

Comment: The third link was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!